# Create a list of midpoints of a sorted list

Tags: r, vector, mean, sorting

I have a sorted vector of numeric values and I would like to create a new vector containing the midpoints of all the pairs. For example:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4)
```

I want to create `b` such that it contains the midpoint of `(1,2)`, `(2,3)` and `(3,4)`:

```
b <- c(1.5, 2.5, 3.5)
```

Comment: `rowMeans(embed(a, 2))` or `zoo::rollmean(a, 2)`

Comment: @Khashaa, `embed` is not high up there on the list of commonly known R functions, so why don't you post an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: @AnandaMahto I am away from my computer now. Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As indicated by @Khashaa in the comments, you can use `rowMeans` after using `embed` or you can use `rollmean` from the "zoo" package.

Example:

```
a <- 1:4

rowMeans(embed(a, 2))
# [1] 1.5 2.5 3.5

library(zoo)
rollmean(a, 2)
# [1] 1.5 2.5 3.5
```

If these are too obscure, a similar concept is to just combine two versions of the vector, one with the first value missing and one with the last value missing, and then use `rowMeans`.

Example:

```
rowMeans(cbind(head(a, -1), tail(a, -1)))
# [1] 1.5 2.5 3.5
```